# MongoDB - Calculate an average from nested arrays

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm trying to create a function to calculate average marks for a student.

I've created the below document:

```
student = {
           "id": 123456,
           "name": "John",
           "surname": "Smith",
           "marks":
                  {
                   "a": [1,5,6,1],
                   "b": [1,1,2,4],
                   "c": [3,5]}

};
```

I know how to calculate it for a specific object - let's say "a", but I have no idea how to merge these 3 objects to get the average for all objects (10 marks).

Below is my code for a specific object:

```
average = function (id,subj) 
     {
          result = [];

          student = db.students.findOne({ "id": 1234567});
          temp_array = student.marks[subj];
          var total = 0;

          for(var i = 0; i<temp_array.length; i++)
          {
                total += temp_array[i];
          }

          average = total / temp_array.length;
          result.push("The average is " + average);
          return result;
      };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an aggregation with [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) in a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage.

This will give you the average for each array `a`, `b` and `c` :

```
db.students.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "id": "1234567"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        a: { $avg: "$marks.a" },
        b: { $avg: "$marks.b" },
        c: { $avg: "$marks.c" }
    }
}])
```

This will gives you the average of combined array `a`, `b` and `c` :

```
db.students.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "id": "1234567"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: 1,
        all: {
            $push: {
                marks: ["$marks.a", "$marks.b", "$marks.c"]
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$all"
}, {
    $unwind: "$all.marks"
}, {
    $unwind: "$all.marks"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: 1,
        marks: { $avg: "$all.marks" }
    }
}])
```

The first [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage is used to push all arrays into another one called `all`. We need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) this array and `marks` should be unwinded twice to obtain one value per document before the last `$group` stage where average is computed